# Post sharp IL level interaction

Tags: .net, compilation, postsharp, il

So I'm looking at PostSharp and I noticed that this isn't using runtime generated proxies but it is actually giving hints to the compilation process to include the aspects within the IL.

So my initial thought were wow, how the heck is this done. Any pointers where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [source code](http://www.postsharp.org/all-downloads/postsharp-1.5-1.5-rtm).  Or google "IL rewriting", it is a common technique.